# After upgrade ubuntu 14.04.1 to 14.04.2 unity won't start

Tags: unity, nvidia, upgrade, xorg

After upgrade my system using Command dist-upgrade and restart system, I log in to my account but unity wont start I See background for a few  seconds and then only black screen and cursor. So I try ctrl+ alt+F6 and enter command startx but same results, black screen. I install different drivers for graphic card (geforce 6100 nforce 405) nvidia-304, nvidia-331 etc. even I re-install ubuntu (14.04.2) but still same problem. When I enter command startx and switching between tty6 and tty7 and again to tty6 I have mesage:

The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:

> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but  has 2 symbols
>                     Ignoring extra symbols
>   Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server

Any solution for this problem???

I will add that I instal KDE and it's looks like everything is working properly.

Sorry for my english ;)

Comment: reboot first and then follow the instructions below. Warnings are not Errors so that is not the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Unity is somehow turned off on your computer. You could turn it back on, by following these steps:

1.Change to `tty1` by pressing `Ctrl + Alt + F1` and log in.
2. Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` by running

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

3. Then run it by doing this:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm
```

4. Press `Ctrl + Alt + F7` (or F8 sometimes)  to get back to the graphical display where there should be a CompizConfig Settings Manager screen sitting there.
5. Find the Unity plugin. Enable it.
6. Everything should spring into life but if it doesn't, you might have to restart. You can do that by going back to `tty1` an d running `sudo reboot`

**NOTE**: If you reach step 5 and do not see Unity on the list, try this: `sudo apt-get -f install && sudo apt-get --reinstall install unity`in `tty1` and then move back to step 3.

Comment: After step 3. I get this message
compizconfig - Info: Backend :ini
compizconfig - info: Integration :true
compizconfig - Info: Profile : default
loading icons...
Then I press Ctrl+alt+F7 /F8 but there is only black screen nothing else.

Comment: Try this: `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ ` and then `unity --reset-icons &disown`. If it doesn't work, give your system a reboot.